# Civi error using D9 webform for contribution payments. "Unable to complete payment! Missing paymentIntentID"

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor, stripe

Creating a donation page using D9 webform and Civi 5.51.3.  Payment processor options are Stripe and Pay Later.  In each case when donation is submitted the Civi error is "Unable to complete payment! Missing paymentIntentID" and the user is sent to most recent Civi page.

I can see similar discussions such as https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/233 and https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/348

Log error:
paymentIntentID not found. $params: Civi\Payment\PropertyBag Object ( [props:protected] => Array ( [default] => Array ( [firstName] => Nubay [lastName] => Admin [billingStreetAddress] => 35 Pickwick Road [billingPostalCode] => 02465 [billingCity] => Newton [country_id] => 1228 [state_province_id] => 1020 [email] => xxx.org [enable_contribution] => 1 [payment_processor_id] => 1 [is_test] => 0 [financial_type_id] => 1 [total_amount] => 10 [billing_address_first_name] => Nubay [billing_address_last_name] => xxx [billing_address_street_address] => xxx [billing_address_postal_code] => 02465 [billing_address_city] => Newton [billing_address_country_id] => 1228 [billing_address_state_province_id] => 1020 [currency] => USD [skipLineItem] => 1 [skipRecentView] => 1 [contactID] => 2 [invoiceID] => 4e8123456789 [tax_amount] => 0 [description] => Webform Payment: Webform Contributions V2 [source] => Test New Webform Contributions [financialType_name] => Donation [financialTypeID] => 1 [non_deductible_amount] => 0 [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_first_name] => Nubay [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_last_name] => xxx [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_street_address] => xxx [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_postal_code] => 02465 [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_city] => Newton [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_country_id] => 1228 [civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_billing_address_state_province_id] => 1020 [op] => SUBMIT YOUR DONATION [form_build_id] => form-P1pw_qZIT_yOiXUxxxve78C1NevEzhJx550fmRtdRc [form_token] => itRvLxCSoVzZCi8xxxXAsPrIEAu5_rpE48IhD_glddA [form_id] => webform_submission_webform_contributions_v2_block_content_2_add_form [payment_instrument_id] => 1 [payment_processor] => 1 [check_permissions] => [contribution_status_id] => Pending [amount] => 10 [contributionID] => 940 [version] => 3 [isRecur] => [error_url] => [setupIntentID] => [paymentMethodID] => [paymentIntentID] => ) ) [suppressLegacyWarnings:protected] => 1 [lastWarning] => )

Comment: Further testing - If options are only to use Pay Later, no error.  Adding Paypal as an option - no error.  so it seems it is a Stripe error that is triggered if Stripe is an option even if not selected.

Comment: Also seems to be close if not the same issue as here - https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/219

Answer (score 1):

Main issue here was that payment method field must be on the same webform page as the actual payment element or it won't work.